# How to show the number of lines of text in a table cell, in a WORD document

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

Having created a table, which cells contains text of 2-10 lines long, I would like to find the way show the number in front of each line in each cell. I would also like the numbers to be continuous in the cells of the same column.

It seems that showing the number of lines in a table cell does not require the same process as showing number of lines in the whole document.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your needs won't be met.

As far as I know, there is no way we can count the number of rows in a cell.

Maybe you can use VBA, but I didn't find out how to get this parameter.

If the number of rows is not very large, I suggest you manually count.

Comment: Thank you. What is VBA?

Comment: VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) is the programming language of Excel and other Office programs.